# Append each input word position and row values to dictionary using python

Tags: python

We have data in a file. We have to read the data in the file and construct a dictionary like take every letter as a key and the value will be the row and column number of the letter present in the file.​Could anyone please help me.?

file data:​

```
"hi how are you"​
"hi hello"​
```

example output:​

```
{'h':[(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3)],​
 'i':[(1,2),(2,1)],​
 ....}​
```

Given below my code:

```
    def read_text():
        d={}
        with open('C:\Users\Desktop\sampletext.txt','r') as g:
            ff=g.readlines()
            ff = map(lambda s: s.strip(), ff)

        print(ff,"ffff")
        row=1
        for line in ff:
            list1=[]
            li = line.split(" ")
            for w in li:
                for k in w:
                    pos = line.index(k)
                    d[k]=(row,pos)
                    #how to append list of values(i.e pos and index) to dict key
        row +=1      
        print(d,"dd")
```

Comment: Your example uses characters brut the title and the example code uses words. Which is it?

Comment: Literal backslashes need to be escaped; or use a raw string for the input file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `line.index` is not a good idea, because (a) you have to scan the same line multiple times, and (b) you will always only get the first position of that character in that line. Also, `d[k]=(row,pos)` in your loop means that you are replacing the list of positions with that single position in each iteration.

Instead, you can just use `enumerate` to iterate lines and characters together with their indices.

```
from collections import defaultdict
text = "hi how are you\nhi hello"
d = defaultdict(list)
for i, line in enumerate(text.splitlines()):
    for j, c in enumerate(line):
        d[c].append((i,j))
```

(Using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here, but you can just as well use a normal `dict` and initialize each character with an empty list.)